# Gaming.SE should get a Google+ Page

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

Now that we can finally have [pages on Google+](https://plus.google.com/pages/create), Gaming should totally get one!

Comment: This is probably a good idea, as long as we can get some volunteers to operate it.  Would you take that on @fredley?

Comment: @GnomeSlice Of course. What do you think our posting volume should be to start off with?

Comment: This this question be closed? Google+ is dead since April 2019.

Comment: @FabianRöling No need to close, I've self-answered and accepted.

Comment: @fredley Magnificent.

Comment: The accepted answer really gave me a laugh.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No

Comment: Haha..........!

Comment: [Cf.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/28146/revisions)

Answer (score 5):

Along the lines of what Dave DuPlantis said in the comments, I fully support this idea, *if we can get people to maintain it.*  If not, I think it looks bad to have a dead page.

Along the lines of keeping it active:

If we can steal an SE dev for a while, perhaps they can patch some feeds up to automatically post, similar to how our twitter account works.  In addition, we need to do a lot of the same things suggested in the meta thread about our Facebook: Post, post, post!  Post good questions!  Post good answers!  Promote our events!  Promote our servers!  There's a whole host of things we can do, but with one caveat:

*We have to be careful not to overdo it.*

People who get bombarded with post after post about us will eventually ignore us.  Remember: moderation.  Find that happy medium and thrive in it.

---

Another thing that can help ease the burden of maintenance, is having several maintainers.  It's a lot easier for 3 people to post twice a week than for one person to post daily.  I think that one post daily (maybe more if G+ explodes and peoples streams get more cluttered) would be a good ratio for keeping us in the public eye, yet not so much that people start to find us annoying.

Comment: I would not be opposed to being a maintainer, on the stipulation that there were others.

Comment: This is good, what we need is a similar setup to the blog, where we can have a pool of users who can help maintain the page.

Comment: I disagree about maintainers.  You need one person who can do it consistently.  I *hate* accounts with inconsistent personality.  In a blog or magazine you can have a particular style with room for individual flavor, but not so much in a social network page.  (And haven't we actually had complaints about the lack of consistency on the blog?) </minirant>

Answer (score -4):

http://www.facebook.com/pages/GamingStackExchange/154617661300474

Comment: I'm not sure why you're pasting that link, could you add a bit of context to your answer?

Comment: Yeah, I don't know.

Comment: @fredley Considering the 15 likes on the Facebook page, I see no point in having yet another social network page, where we have almost no publicity.

Comment: @mordi2k I've seen quite a few SE'ers on Google+ before I got suspended.

Comment: @mordi2k Wait, so the way to make more impact on social media is to target fewer social media sites?

Comment: @fredley, I think targeting isn't as important as providing a consistent, active presence. Pretty much every site is cluttered with pages put up by companies/people/sites who simply wanted a presence without a purpose behind it: making it worthwhile requires constant effort, and that may be a reason behind some people's reluctance to support the idea, uncertainty as to where the effort will come from.